# Why does msyqli_real_escape_string() not escape multiple backslashes properly?

Tags: php, mysql

Given this SQL

```
UPDATE `mytable` 
SET `mycolumn`='karla bailey-pearapppppppp\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\' 
WHERE `id`=5619
```

Why will `mysqli_real_escape_string()` not escape this string properly?

Trying to use this SQL query after escaping the column's value produces this mysqli error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''karla bailey-pearapppppppp\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\' at line 3"

Is there a limit to the number of backslashes that can be escaped?

Comment: Why are you still using mysqli_real_escape_string() and not using bind variables.... then this would be a non-issue

Comment: where and how is `msyqli_real_escape_string()` implemented in this? there's nothing in your question to support that. btw, it's `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and not `msyqli_real_escape_string()` so if that's what you're using or not; show it.

Comment: Looks like the error is between the = and karla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem. The application checks for the value length > column maximum, and if the value is too great, truncates the value AFTER the escape is done - thereby breaking the escaped value (very isolated case where this would occur, this code has been in place for years).

Ergo, can't truncate a value that ends in backslashes after the value is already escaped.

Answer (score 2):

Are you escaping the ENTIRE string? e.g.

```
$sql = "UPDATE .... \\\\\\\'";
$escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $sql);
```

If so, that's incorrect. You are trashing the string by doing that. You'll also be escaping the `'` that delimit your where clause value. Escaping should be performed only **VALUES** that you're inserting into the string. e.g.

```
$name = "Miles O'Brien"; // ' in name would cause syntax error
$bad_sql = "SELECT '$name'";
$broken_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $bad_sql);
// produces: SELECT \'Miles O\'Brien\'


$ok_sql = "SELECT '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name) . "'";
// produces: SELECT 'Miles O\'Brien';
```

Comment: Nice catch on fixing their *hopefully* typo `msyqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: No, I am escaping only the value. Working up a sample script now.

Comment: I'm baffled. When I try this outside the application, it does not fail. I can absolutely reproduce in the application, right down to using the test code I created that makes the connection, escapes the string, runs the UPDATE query. Fails when I am using the value from the page (via POST), but succeeds when I use that same value in a test script. The value is passed using rawurlencode(), and so in my test script I'm using the encoded value and then using rawurldecode(), but still works every time.